# How to override Robolectric standard shadow class with custom class?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, robolectric, nosuchmethoderror

I am writing a simple application that connects to a Bluetooth low energy device. The code that connects to the device is on a HandlerThread so, to make the handler thread work in a unit test I used [robolectric](http://robolectric.org/).

After using robolectric, the handler thread work perfectly, but there was another problem.

Robolectric does not allow me to mock the BluetoothDevice class as the robolectric [ShadowBluetoothDevice](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/robolectric-shadows/shadows-core/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowBluetoothDevice.java) class **does not contain the method** connectGatt(...). So, at runtime I get the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.connectGatt(Landroid/content/Context;ZLandroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback;)Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt;

at com.example.BLEGattTest.setup(BLEGattTest.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:176)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:142)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

So, I was thinking, if I could just override the ShadowBluetoothDevice, I can actually make this work?

My Code:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = Config.NONE)
    public class BLEGattTest {

        private BLEGattScanner scanner;

        private Customer customer;

        private BluetoothDevice device;

        @Before
        public void setup(){

            customer = new Customer();
            customer.setDevice(device);

            device = Mockito.mock(BluetoothDevice.class);
            when(device.connectGatt(any(Context.class), anyBoolean(), any(BluetoothGattCallback.class))).thenReturn(null);

            scanner = new BLEGattScanner(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
            scanner.start();
        }

        @After
        public void tearDown() throws InterruptedException {
            if(scanner != null){
                scanner.stopThread();
                scanner.join(1000);
            }
        }

        @Test
        public void testMocks(){
            Assert.assertEquals("asdf", device.getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You add the device and after that, you mock it. That cannot work - you need to mock it and then set the device. At `customer.setDevice(device)` the `device` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks!!! I tried a lot of things for 5 hours before I posted this.. and the I missed a simple thing.. that was really stupid .. haha

Anyways!! thanks.... @thst

Comment: I will add it as an answer then if you don't mind :-)

Comment: @Aanal Raj Basaula can you tell me if there is a way to test my callback function also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add the device and after that, you mock it. That cannot work - you need to mock it and then set the device.

At `customer.setDevice(device)` the device is undefined.